# Is there any way to use the Photosynth app only to take photos, in full resolution?

Tags: camera

I have briefly used the new Photosynth app and noticed that the output has a fairly low resolution.

I suppose a compromise has been made for the processing power and bandwidth available on a mobile phone, but it makes the end result less than impressive.

Is there any way to use the app only to make full resolution photographs, which can then be processed on a desktop computer using the [Image Composite Editor](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/ice/) for Photosynth?

Or is there a third-party app which has a similar camera interface for taking photos to make 'synths'?

Here is a QR code to get the Photosynth app:

[image: Photosynth]

Comment: @TomWijsman: It's not in the UK marketplace yet either.  Try scanning the QR code I have added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an app called [Turbo Camera](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/7fcd71c4-0d36-42ca-b11d-0587ab45b7ef) that will take a very large burst of shots very quickly, and gives you options on image resolution from 640x480 through to much larger.

Once you've got your stream of photos, you can either save individual frames, or whole sections to the camera roll, and can then take them off the phone for processing in ICE at your leisure.

I've been fairly happy with the performance of the app, but I've not tried tying it into ICE.

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible. I believe this is due to not being able to write high resolution images to flash memory and track smoothly at the same time. The application may also run out of memory when stitching and blending high resolution images.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't really apply to my question.  But how do you know about what you said before that?  Thanks.

Comment: The last part kind of does since it forces you to stitch it before putting it in your camera roll. I found some information about resolution here http://photosynth.net/discussion.aspx?cat=c76bfe71-d042-4aec-b49b-b48b67d7be96&dis=aec0194a-0ebc-40a7-a338-17edd8094965, it is a bit old but it still seems to be applicable. If you want high resolution images you would have to take the photos in the normal camera app and then stitch them using the desktop app.

Comment: Okay, thanks, but what I am asking is how to take the photographs (in hi-res) without any processing at all done on the phone, but with the camera GUI which makes it easier to make sure all areas of the vista have been covered.

Comment: Unfortunately (as per the last part of my comment) you cannot do this in the current version and you would have to use the normal camera app.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not possible to have a full 360° of highest resolution images in the memory. So, if you want to be a pro manual stitching is most likely the way to go. Until they come with some smarter approach of displaying / stitching the images that uses temporary memory. In any case, it really looks like they've rushed this app...